# Can Zarya block Tracer's ultimate after being stuck?

Tags: overwatch

When playing as **Tracer**, I managed to stick my ultimate on **Zarya** who was half health, and while she didn't have her orb around her. However when the bomb exploded she didn't die.

I didn't get to see if she had activated her orb after. So my question to you is, can **Zarya** block the **Tracer's** ulimate even if stuck? Or was there some other factor that stopped her from dying?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Zarya's barriers will absorb all damage dealt to the hero they're on. It's impossible to damage a hero protected by Zarya's barriers, even with barrier-piercing effects such as Firestrike or Dragonstrike.

Comment: source:? Any source?

Comment: Me playing Zarya.

Comment: good enough. ha ha ha

Comment: I'd like to add that Zarya's barriers will absorb *all* damage from the last attack hitting them, even if it breaks the barrier and most of the damage is overkill, as happens with Pulse Bomb or MEKA explosion. Unlike, e.g., Sound Barrier.